# I want to add the stream obtained using StreamProvider to the state of NotifierProvider, but I don't know how to do it

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

When you have code like the following, how should you set the stream obtained from the streamProvider to the state of a Notifier?

```dart
final streamProvider = StreamProvider
    .autoDispose<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, String>(
  (ref) =>
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collectionId').snapshots(),
);

final notifierProvider =
    NotifierProvider.autoDispose<ListNotifier, ListState>(ListNotifier.new);

class ListNotifier extends AutoDisposeNotifier<ListState> {
  @override
  ListState build() {
    return const ListState(list: []);
  }
}

@freezed
class ListState with _$ListState {
  const factory ListState({required List<Map<String, dynamic>> list}) =
      _ListState;
  const ListState._();
}
```